# Stick div on screen when user is scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make my div `right` to stick on screen when user is scrolling. This is example situation: https://jsfiddle.net/gwjehuzf/

I tried a lot, but without success. Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
        console.log("a");
        var newPos = $(document).scrollTop() + 400;
        $('.right').css({ top: newPos });
    }

    else {
        $('.right').css({ top: 400 });
    }
})
```

for some reason is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: give CSS `position: fixed` and it shall work

Comment: @JoykalInfotech it's not. Graph disappear after adding `fixed`.

Comment: Have you tried using position: sticky?

Comment: position:sticky; top:0;

Comment: @godfather sticky and top crash hover effect: https://jsfiddle.net/oLh6n3mj/

Comment: you mean on icon?

Comment: ive updated the answer plz check it

Comment: check my answer bro it will help you to under stand

Comment: look over my code bro. i have changed a bit it might be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use css .right{position:sticky; top:0; overflow:hidden;}

Comment: Why with that hover effect is not applied? https://jsfiddle.net/oLh6n3mj/

Comment: i think its overlapping try to add overflow:hidden;

Comment: You can add demo for more explanation

Comment: you can test the code  on jsfiddle you will see that  he have under the age eyes icons thats what he meant by hover effect not applied

Comment: hello @dafie did my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add few **CSS**, we'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css in your code

```css
.right {
   position: sticky; 
   top: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: Sticky is not yet supported correctly by all major browsers, refer to its caniuse table : https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky. I would suggest using `position: fixed` instead.

Comment: Why with that solution hover effect is not applied? https://jsfiddle.net/oLh6n3mj/

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript needed for that. Use `position: fixed` for the `.right` div. 
If it disappears, give it a width (maybe about 80%) and `right: 0`:

```css
.right {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not happen when user scroll

Comment: @NullDev I want to avoid applying `width`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `position: sticky` to `.right` and setting `top: 0`.

```
.right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Your JSFiddle corrected [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddie19/7yL0g8nc/3/).

Comment: This seems to work, but I have another problem - why hover effect is not visible on image? Without `position` and `right` hover is working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/oLh6n3mj/

Comment: That solution seems to crash hover effect: https://jsfiddle.net/oLh6n3mj/